# Users limitations - in database or direct to file? (flexibility vs. performance?)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, email, limit

the users registered in a web site will have the possibility to send invitations to the friends. I want to add a daily limit for the number of invitations that a user may send.

Initially I've just added a limit (40) in the php file, but then I thought it would be better to give to the administrators the possibility to change this limit, so I've added this limit in the database. But now every time a user want to send invitations the database will be used. Would this affect the performance?

How would you configure this feature?

Comment: This is a bit of an open-ended question. it depends on how many users you have, how many invites they send and how you've implemented it in the database/application. If you could add some more information then I think you'll get some more useful answers.

Comment: I'm a bit with @jamec_c, but on the other hand: what sort of situation can you figure out where the retrieval of this limit is the thing that slow everything down? I'd say if you have enough hits on this that it's a problem, you'll have other worries and sollutions in line for everything, and this will be a non-issue

Comment: @James We hope to have at least 10.000 users, and every user get a bonus if he add another user to the website, so they will send as many invitations as they can (this is why we add the limit). Every invitation has a unique key, that is also saved in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: just put it in the database. :)

Complete story: It should not be a performance hit. Everything (the user itself, the usernames of the recipient, loads of stuff from your page) will be coming from your database. you shouldn't care.

If you have a REALLY big userbase, and it becomes an issue, I'm sure there are other places to do performance updates (like use memcached for all sorts of stuff). But if you want to "cache" it, I guess you could retrieve it once while loggin in and put it in the session. Use this value to substract and check etc. then ALSO check once against the database (in the background) to make sure there isn't any sort of freakish thing going on for this user. But this can be async, and does not have as big of an impact for the user-experience.

In the rare case the session says it's ok, but the database says it isn't, just send the user an error. The other way around, might need the user to re-login. But it will be rare or even impossible if you implement it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on hardware but a 400,000 row table (10,000 * 40) isn't that huge in MySQL standards. I think you'll be fine.

Just make sure that you've built it sensibly and from how you've described it that there's an index on the column that stores the unique invite code.